# Is there any different between two types of union in spark streaming

Tags: performance, apache-spark, spark-streaming, distributed-computing, data-stream

Dstream provide two types of `union` :

```
StreamingContext.union(Dstreams)

Dstream.union(anotherDstream)
```

So I want to know what is the different, especially in parallelism performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source code of the two operations, there is no difference other than one taking a single `DStream` as input and the other a list.

[StreamingContext](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/StreamingContext.scala):

```
def union[T: ClassTag](streams: Seq[DStream[T]]): DStream[T] = withScope {
  new UnionDStream[T](streams.toArray)
}
```

[Dstream](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/DStream.scala):

```
def union(that: DStream[T]): DStream[T] = ssc.withScope {
  new UnionDStream[T](Array(this, that))
}
```

Hence, which one you use depends on your preference, there is no performance gains to be had. When you have a list of streams to unite, the method in `StreamingConext` simplifies the code a bit, hence, it could be preferable in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Your claim "`DStream` provide two types of union" is not quite right.

The [ref](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.streaming.html) mentions differnt signatures, and more specifically different classes that provide the union operation.

> **StreamingContext.union(*dstreams)**
>
> Create a unified DStream from multiple DStreams of the same type and same slide duration.
>
> **DStream.union(other)**
>
> Return a new DStream by unifying data of another DStream with this DStream.
>      Parameters:    other – Another DStream having the same interval (i.e., slideDuration) as this DStream.

The later is discussed in the [Spark User List](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/what-does-DStream-union-do-td17673.html): "The union function simply returns a DStream with the elements from both. This is the same behavior as when we call union on RDDs".

---

Source code of [StreamingContext](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/streaming/context.py):

```
def union(self, *dstreams):
    ...
    first = dstreams[0]
    jrest = [d._jdstream for d in dstreams[1:]]
    return DStream(self._jssc.union(first._jdstream, jrest), self, first._jrdd_deserializer)
```

Source code of [DStream](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/streaming/dstream.py):

```
def union(self, other):
    return self.transformWith(lambda a, b: a.union(b), other, True)
```

You can see that the first uses recursion (as expected), while the other uses `transformWith`, which is defined in the same class and transforms each RDD.

---

The thing to remember is [Level of Parallelism in Data Receiving](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/streaming-programming-guide.html#level-of-parallelism-in-data-receiving), where in cases that the data receiving becomes a bottleneck in the system, then consider parallelizing the data receiving process would be a good idea.

As a result, the process of applying the `union()` method to multiple `DStreams` is encouraged`, which resulted in providing a method to do this easily, while keeping your code clean. IMHO, there wouldn't be a difference in performance.